# How to sum specific column when key matches in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have sample data as below:

```
(id,code,key,value)
1,A,p,10
2,B,q,20
3,B,p,30
3,B,q,20
3,C,t,60
3,C,q,20
```

After storing it into PIG, i need output like below:

```
O/P:

(A,{(p,10)})

(B,{(q,40),(p,30)})

(C,{(t,60)},(q,20))
```

We can drop id, and need output that adds the sum of all value that match with the key for specific code. in the above example we can see for code B- q,20 is twice, hence added and became q,40.

Below is my code but not able to get the exact output:

```
Lo = load 'pivot.txt' using PigStorage (',') as (id:chararray, code:chararray, key:chararray, value:int);
Aa = group L by (code);
Bb = foreach Aa {AUX = foreach Lo generate $0,$2,$3;generate group, AUX;}`

dump Bb:
(A,{(1,p,10)})
(B,{(3,q,20),(3,p,30),(2,q,20)})
(C,{(3,t,60),(3,q,20)})
```

I am not able to proceed further, help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rohith

Comment: can you share the final output required ?

Comment: This is the final output: it should add the 'value' field if 'key' is the same.

    (A,{(p,10)})

    (B,{(q,40),(p,30)})

    (C,{(t,60)},(q,20))

Comment: This is the final output: it should add the 'value' field if 'key' is the same.
Example: for code B: (q,20) repeats twice, hence it should be added and result should be (q,40). Only if key is same...

As of now for the above code i was able to only get till get this output:

(A,{(p,10)})

(B,{(q,20),(p,30),(q,20)})

(C,{(q,20),(t,60)})

But i need final output as below:


    (A,{(p,10)})


    (B,{(q,40),(p,30)})


    (C,{(t,60)},(q,20))

Comment: Added an approach, play around it to achieve your objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pig Script :**

```
input_data = LOAD 'input.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int,code:chararray,key:chararray,value:int);
req_stats = FOREACH(GROUP input_data BY (code,key)) GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (code,key), SUM(input_data.value) AS value;
req_stats_fmt = FOREACH(GROUP req_stats BY code) GENERATE group AS code, req_stats.(key,value);
DUMP req_stats_fmt;
```

**Input :**

```
1,A,p,10
2,B,q,20
3,B,p,30
3,B,q,20
3,C,t,60
3,C,q,20
```

**Output : DUMP req_stats_fmt**

```
(A,{(p,10)})
(B,{(q,40),(p,30)})
(C,{(t,60),(q,20)})
```

Comment: Thanks a ton brother, that worked...Appreciate your great help :)

Comment: updated @RohithAnand : If it helps in achieving the objective you can accept the answer.